# How can I sort Arrays in a Collection?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a a List of Objects. Those Objects have (amongst others) a private int Array (if it helps, I can transfer it into a List). There is a public Getter for  this Array. All Arrays are the same size.

I want to sort the Object based on their Arrays like this:

```
Unsorted:
{[0, 1, 4, 5], 
 [0, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 2]}

Sorted:
{[0, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 4, 5]}
```

In Words (it's called lexicographical):

- compare the first int of each array
- if they are equal, compare the next int of each array (and so on)
- if they aren't equal the result of the comparison is the end result.

I manage to search them for e.g. only the first element of the array with a normal Comparator but I don't know how to search them for all.

Comment: To be clear: my Array is a int[] not an Integer[]

Comment: This is really interesting but... You do not show us what you've tried. What is stopping you from producing a code?

Comment: If the arrays are private, how do you expect to use them to sort your Objects? You can't compare private properties.

Comment: Are all arrays same in size?

Comment: Whats actually the criteria which array is geater or less than another? The sum? Their entropy (how much sorted they are)? Their min/max values? ... Downvote until clarified - this question is too vague (broad).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A nice Java 8 solution is

```
static final Comparator<CustomObject> COMPARATOR = (o1, o2) -> {
    int[] arr1 = o1.getArray();
    int[] arr2 = o2.getArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
                    .map(i -> Integer.compare(arr1[i], arr2[i]))
                    .filter(i -> i != 0)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(0);
};
```

Then, given a `List<CustomObject>`, you can do

```
list.sort(COMPARATOR);
```

(The `Comparator` only works for arrays of the same length. You may want to modify it).

Comment: Although I like the _Java8_ness of this solution, I don't get particularly excited about its running time aspects. The `map` function would need to do all the integer comparisons, whereas we can short-circuit the rest once we find first pair of unequal values.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade No, it will short-circuit, You can stick a `peek` in to check if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 8):

> I have a Collection (preferable some kind of List) of Objects
>   [...]
>   Now I want to sort the Object based on their Arrays

For it to be meaningful at all, the `Collection` in question must be one that preserves order and allows you to reorder elements.  In terms of the high-level Collections interfaces, only `List` has the required properties, so let's presume that your `Collection` is, indeed, a `List`.

The standard way to sort a `List` is to use one of the two `Collections.sort()` methods.  One requires the list elements to implement `Comparable`, and the other, more general, one requires you to provide an object implementing `Comparator` for use in determining the desired relative order of the objects.

Arrays do not implement `Comparable` (which is equivalent to saying that they have no "natural order"), but the class of the objects containing them could be made to do so.  It is probably better form, however, to write a separate `Comparator` class that implements the order you want, and use an instance of that class.

Answer (score 6):

If I am understanding it correctly, following straightforward approach should work:

```
public class SortArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<int[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<>(4);
        listOfArrays.add(new int[]{0, 1, 4, 5});
        listOfArrays.add(new int[]{0, 0, 2, 3});
        listOfArrays.add(new int[]{0, 1, 1, 2});
        Collections.sort(listOfArrays, (o1, o2) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
                if (o1[i] < o2[i])
                    return -1;
                if (o1[i] > o2[i])
                    return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        listOfArrays.forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
    }
}
```

It produces:

```
[0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 4, 5]
```

and that's what you seem to expect.

Comment: What would happen if o2 was longer than o1?

Comment: Results are undefined ;). I had asked OP, and will update this answer if there is something definitive that is needed in that case.

Comment: And i meant shorter ;)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your class looks something like this, and you can't modify it.

```
final class MyClass
{
  private final int[] key;

  MyClass(int[] key)
  {
    this.key = key.clone();
  }

  public int[] getKey()
  {
    return key.clone();
  }
}
```

Then, you can define an ordering for instances of `MyClass` by implementing the `Comparator` interface. To be more general, I'm actually going to implement a comparator for `int[]`:

```
final class IntArrayComparator
  implements Comparator<int[]>
{

  @Override
  public int compare(int[] a, int[] b)
  {
    int n = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx) {
      if (a[idx] != b[idx])
        return (a[idx] < b[idx]) ? -1 : +1;
    }
    return a.length - b.length;
  }
}
```

Given this new comparator, and your existing type, it's easy to sort:

```
final class Test
{
  public static void main(String... arg)
  {
    /* Create your list somehow... */
    List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MyClass(new int[]{0, 1, 4, 5}));
    list.add(new MyClass(new int[]{0, 0, 2, 3}));
    list.add(new MyClass(new int[]{0, 1, 1, 2}));

    /* Now sort the list. */
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getKey, new IntArrayComparator()));

    /* Display the result... */
    list.stream().map(MyClass::getKey).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

You should get the output:

```
[0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 4, 5]
```

The `comparing()` factory method I am using takes two arguments: a `Function` to "extract" a key from each object in the list, and a `Comparator` that can compare the extracted keys. If the extracted key has a natural ordering, and implements `Comparable` (for example, it's a `String`), then it isn't necessary to specify a `Comparator`.

Alternatively, if you can modify `MyClass`, you could give it a natural order by implementing `Comparable` and moving the `int[]` comparison to its `compareTo()` method, as shown in other answers. Then you can use the `sort()` method without arguments.

Answer (score 4):

In order to sort a list of arrays of int, you want a function that performs a *lexicographic comparison* of an array of ints. This is usually expressed as a `Comparator<int[]>` in Java. The usual way to implement such a function is to compare corresponding values left-to-right until a mismatch is found; that mismatch determines the order. If the end of an array is reached without finding a mismatch, the shorter array is usually considered less than the longer one. If the lengths are equal, and all values are equal, the arrays are considered equal.

Other answers have used anonymous inner classes or lambdas for this function, but for things like this I prefer an ordinary method that has the right "shape", that is, that takes two `int[]` arguments and returns an `int` which is the result of the comparison. This enables it to be used as the target of a method reference.

```
int arrayCompare(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int len = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int c = Integer.compare(a[i], b[i]);
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return a.length - b.length;
}
```

Note the careful use of `Integer.compare()` instead of subtraction, avoiding potential problems with overflow. Usage would be as follows:

```
    List<int[]> arrays = Arrays.asList(
        new int[] { 0, 1, 4, 5 },
        new int[] { 0, 0, 2, 3 },
        new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 2 }
    );

    arrays.sort(this::arrayCompare);
    arrays.forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

In JDK 9, lexicographic array comparison functions have been added to the `Arrays` class. See [`Arrays.compare(int[], int[])`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-int:A-int:A-). There are also overloads for the other primitive types and for reference types. The `int[]` overload replaces the `arrayCompare` function I wrote above, so you can rewrite the sort call as follows:

```
    arrays.sort(Arrays::compare);
```

The advantage of the comparison functions in the `Arrays` class is that they can be handled specially by the JVM, which can, for example, use vector instructions to speed up array comparisons.

For your specific problem, it looks like you don't have a list of `int[]`, but you have a list of objects of type `MyObject` that have an `int[]` that you want to use as the sort key. Suppose the way to get the array is by calling the method `getArray()`. You can sort the list as follows:

```
    myObjects.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getArray, Arrays::compare));
```

Comment: Does JDK9 have support for lexicographically comparing Lists? If so, can you pass in a Comparator<T> to say how individual elements should be compared?

Comment: @PaulBoddington Not in the JDK. But Guava has `Ordering.lexicographical()` that does this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this object:

```
public class Foo {

    private int[] values;

    public Foo(int[] values) { 
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

To make a list of objects:

```
ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
foos.add(new Foo(new int[] {0, 1, 4, 5}));
foos.add(new Foo(new int[] {0, 0, 2, 3}));
foos.add(new Foo(new int[] {0, 1, 1, 2}));
```

Now we want to sort our list of objects, so the first thing we should do is make our object implement `Comparable`. You should read more [what the Comparable interface is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), and [how to implement it](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-comparable-example/).

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    ...
}
```

At this point your compiler will complain that you haven't implemented all of the methods required by the interface. So do that.

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    ...
    public int compareTo(Foo f) {
        // Return a negative integer if this < f
        // Return zero if this == f
        // Return a positive integer if this > f
    }
}
```

As far as the actual comparison logic goes, your question is not very specific about the exact rules you are using to compare two objects. However, from the example, I can kind of guess that these are your rules:

- Compare the first number of each array.

  - If they are equal, repeat this process using the next number of each array.
  - Otherwise, the result of this comparison is the final result.

You don't really specify what to do if one array is shorter than the other. I'll leave writing the actual algorithm to you (although others answers appear to have done that for you). However, I will point out that because values is a private field, you won't be able to use that field for comparison unless you implement a getter for the field or make it public.

```
public int[] getValues() { return values; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your array is `private` and you do want to provide an accessor method then implement `Comparable` for the class and do something like below code.

If you have an accessor method then do this in a `Comparator`.

This code `does not assume arrays to be of same size` so it works for different size arrays. Please change according to your need.

PS - not compiled/tested

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
        CustomClass other = (CustomClass ) o;

        int i = 0;
        while (i <= numbers.length && i <= other.numbers.length) {
            if (numbers[i] < other.numbers[i])
                return -1;
            else if (numbers[i] > other.numbers[i])
                return 1;
            ++i;
        }

        if (numbers.length < other.numbers.length)
            return -1;
        else if (numbers.length > other.numbers.length)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
```